# Loopback - Model instance to JavaScript object

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have the following code:

```
MyUser.find().then(function (res) {
    console.log(res[0]);
});
```

This effectively logs a model instance, which is fine. However, if I try to do this:

```
MyUser.find().then(function (res) {
    delete res[0].name;
    console.log(res[0]);
});
```

This delete statement doesn't work. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Could you define "doesn't work" please? Throw an exception? Doesn't remove the property? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any detail about the elements of the `res` array, but here is a possible cause.

Properties added to an Object using [Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) are, by default, immutable. Specifically, the descriptor property [configurable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Configurable_attribute), which defaults to `false`, determines whether the property is deletable.